# OnGUI and Key Press

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I can see the UI results when I create an empty game object, attach a script to it containing the following code, and press play:

```
public class OnGUI_test : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnGUI ()
    {
            GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 100));
            GUILayout.Button("Click me!");
            GUILayout.EndArea();
    }
}
```

But why is that the following doesn't run when I try to add code to check for a key press?

```
public class OnGUI_test : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnGUI ()
    {
        if ( Input.GetKeyDown( KeyCode.Escape ) )
        {
            GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 100));
            GUILayout.Button("Click me");
            GUILayout.EndArea();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I correct it to see the button when Esc is pressed?

Thank you

Comment: Read the docs: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html `Input.GetKeyDown` needs to be called from the `Update` function and it gets reset on each new frame.

Comment: it doesn't "need" to be called from Update in order to function like GUI events "need" to be called from OnGUI, the only way to know whether a key is held after the KeyDown event in  OnGUI is to either cache the value during the KeyDown and KeyUp events or to use Input.GetKey on every OnGUI call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to only draw the Gui elements when the escape button is pressed check `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape)` then it won't get reset on each frame and will always return true when escape is pressed

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `Down` from `GetKeyDown`.

If you want to persist between Escape presses, toggle a flag (something like `isPanelVisible`) on every `GetKeyDown`, then draw the UI when flag is true.

Comment: Thanks Geri. Helpful advice to use `isPanelVisible`